# Quero seleccionar um valor especifico no collection_select, como faço?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Bom dia, Estou a trabalhar com ruby on Rails e estou com uma pequena dificuldade. Tenho um valor numa variável @n, e tenho um collection_select que me vai buscar todos os valores de uma colecção. o que quero fazer é seleccionar logo o valor que está na variável @n. o valor que está em @n é "cats". eu tenho: `<%= f.collection_select :isolated_id, @isolateds, :id, :name, prompt: true %>` onde `@isolateds` é a minha colecção que inclui o nome "cats".

Quando vou ver o codigo em html tenho:

```
<select id="resist_isolated_id" name="resist[isolated_id]">
      <option value="">Please select</option>
      <option value="1">cenas</option>
      ...
      <option value="22">cats</option>
</select>
```

Eu queria: `<option value="22" selected="selected">cats</option>` e se na colection_select colocar `:selected => 22` ele faz-me isso, o problema é que se for outro nome qualquer, sem ser "cats", eu não vou saber à partida qual é o seu "value" correspondente, assim eu queria passar directamente a variável @n mas quando faço `:selected => "@n"`, não dá nada. Alguém me pode ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O selected funciona com o valor, e não com o texto, no seu caso, o @n deveria ter "22" como conteúdo, assim funcionaria.

Comment: Pois, o meu problema é que eu tenho mesmo que trabalhar com o texto, existe alguma maneira, ou existe alguma maneira de colocar o valor igual ao texto?

Comment: <%= f.collection_select :isolated_id, @isolateds, :id, :name, prompt: true %>

No lugar de :id, vc pode colocar :nome.

Comment: Obrigada assim já deu :)

Comment: Só mais uma perguntinha, como eu faço para ficar disable, a seguir ao :selected => "#{@n}" estou a colocar :disable => "disable" e não me está a dar.

Comment: Veja se resolve seu problema: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23819157/how-to-make-a-collection-select-disabled-in-rails-4